# Unable to change PHP version in Ubuntu 18.04 terminal

Tags: php, linux, apache, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

This question has been asked multiple times but non of them worked for me. I need to change my terminal's version to 7.4.

When I do `phpinfo()` it gives **7.4.10** but in terminal `php -v` it always show **5.6.0**

I've done:

```
$ sudo a2dismod php5.6
$ sudo a2enmod php7.4
$ sudo service apache2 restart

set PATH="/usr/bin/php7.4/bin:$PATH"

sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar7.4
sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar7.4

sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

This show below result:

[image: PHP version]

Comment: When you test phpinfo() from browser, then it may be the php-fpm version, not the php cli version.

Comment: @MarkusZeller how can I fix this? Issue is I'm using Laravel which needs php 7.4. So when I run migration or other artisan commands it gives error. Which is because it get 5.6 version during that (it's what I think, maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: `sudo a2dismod php7.4`, then `sudo apt install php7.4-fpm`, then `a2enmod php7.4-fpm` and `sudo service apache2 restart`. With the `update-alternatives --config php` you just set the php-cli version.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following command in the command line:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.1
```

Simply provide the desired PHP version in the above line of command.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of PHP aren't available for install, because the LTS (*Long Term Support*) versions of that version 18 of Ubuntu, and other derivatives, are now expired.

> Ubuntu 18.04 LTS had normal LTS support for five years until May 2023
> and has paid ESM support available from Canonical for an additional
> five years until April 2028.
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_(Bionic_Beaver)

> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`  You are about to add the
> following PPA:  Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x, PHP 8.x
> and most requested extensions are included. Only Supported Versions of
> PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu
> Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask
> for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be
> provided.

---

Upgrading the system won't work either, up to a point, dependencies are missing.
Upgrading from `apt` won't work in this situation, neither `update-alternatives` as the remote PPA will block further installation on expired LTS systems.

There is no proper solutions beside a fresh install of a supported recent LTS version.

---

However, to force install the last PHP versions, including the last development versions, **we have to compile from sources**.

This is really **not recommended** in a production server.

Get the last source archive from the PHP website:

https://www.php.net/downloads.php (See readme.md for tweaks)

```
./buildconf
./configure
make -j4
sudo make install
php -v
# PHP 8.3.0 (cli) (built: Dec 25 2023 00:00:00) (NTS DEBUG)
```